# In which year did Hippocrates introduce the historical conception of disease?

Tags: medicine

I am aware the notion of disease 'having a course' comes from [Hippocrates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippocrates), who is known as the father of modern medicine in part due to this reason. From this fact I wonder if someone knows and could pinpoint the exact year when Hippocrates introduce 'the historical conception of disease'.

Comment: I am afraid, we will never know. Even the life dates of ancient figures, including Hippocrates, are educated guesses. Their writings did not come out with dates either, and we only have copies of copies of copies, if that. You can find what little is known in [Nuland's Doctors](https://books.google.com/books/about/Doctors.html?id=hVePdRGsX2sC), but c. 420 BC (c. from Latin *circa*, about) is probably the best you can get.

Comment: Ah, you may be right.